# Microsoft Excel not recognizing cell data as date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm working with a set of dates that need to be utilized in an if function. In the event the date is more than 365 days from today, it is false and vice versa for under 365 days. My problem stems from the way the dates are generating.

For example:
23AU29
24JN15
23SP22

Some dates pop up as (23APR14) in which case excel does recognize the 3 letter month, but for the 2 letter months Excel does not recognize this as a date and only offers general formatting.
I'm aware I can create a custom list but considering how many different possibilities there are, I'd rather not.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps change the two letter month abbreviations to three letter abbreviations?

Comment: Sometimes its the most obvious things that we forget to check..... Thanks!